# Visual Studio: Context Menu on Solution Explorer too long, can I add a sub menu or a toolbar above solution explorer?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, vs-extensibility

My context menu on my solution explorer is way too long, although I am not complaining, this is due to the fact that I have a lot of extensions installed. Most commands I can find... but there is one pesky command that always is difficult to spot and I use it all the time.

"Set as Startup Project"

Is there a way (or an extension) that allows me to add a sub menu to the context menu for commands I use regularly or an extension for adding a toolbar on the solution window?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It doesn't require an extension, you can alter the menu to your heart's content without coding.  Use Tools > Customize > Commands tab.  Click the Toolbar radio button and select "Context Menus | Project and Solution Context Menus | Solution".  You should see your too-long context menu.  Move a favorite command in a better spot with the Move Up button.  Use the Add New Menu button to add a sub-menu.